# PHP Merge 2 arrays with start/endtimestamp

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I am trying to merge 2 php arrays in a "special" way. I want to "merge" overlapping timestamps. For example take these arrays:

```
array (size=6)   0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'starttime' => int 1397635320
      'endtime' => int 1397635440   
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'starttime' => int 1397635740
      'endtime' => int 1397635920   
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'starttime' => int 1397636700
      'endtime' => int 1397637300   
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'starttime' => int 1397641260
      'endtime' => int 1397641980   
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'starttime' => int 1397642640
      'endtime' => int 1397642760   
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'starttime' => int 1397643240
      'endtime' => int 1397647740
```

And:

```
array (size=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'starttime' => int 1397636580
      'endtime' => int 1397637300
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'starttime' => int 1397641080
      'endtime' => int 1397641980
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'starttime' => int 1397643120
      'endtime' => int 1397647800
```

We can display this as:
[image: http://upload.mattie-systems.nl/uploads/96059-knipsel.png]

I want to merge the bottem one to the top one, however it is possible that the bottom one for example starts BEFORE the top one so in stat case I must have the starttime from the bottom one! (always the "longest" time possible)

I've tried for a few hours but I still cannot get the output i want (one array with the "longest" timespans possible)

Just some code I tried:

```
  public static function mergeOutageArrays($db_outages, $report_outages)
    {
    $returnarray = array();

    foreach($db_outages as $db_outage)
      {

      $db_starttime = $db_outage['starttime'];
      $db_endtime = $db_outage['endtime'];

      //now match this with report outages

      foreach ($report_outages as $report_outage)
        {
        $report_starttime = $report_outage['starttime'];
        $report_endtime = $report_outage['endtime'];

        if($db_starttime == $report_starttime && $db_endtime == $report_endtime) //easy, everything matches
          $returnarray[] = $report_outage;

        else if($db_starttime == $report_starttime && $db_endtime <= $report_endtime)//seems the db end time falls short, use report
          $returnarray[] = $report_outage;

        else if($db_starttime == $report_starttime && $db_endtime > $report_endtime)//seems the report end time falls short, use db
          $returnarray[] = $db_outage;

        else if($db_starttime <= $report_starttime && $db_endtime == $report_endtime)//seems report starts to late, use db
          $returnarray[] = $db_outage;

        else if($db_starttime > $report_starttime && $db_endtime == $report_endtime)//seems db starts to late, use report
          $returnarray[] = $report_outage;

        elseif($db_starttime <= $report_starttime && $db_endtime > $report_endtime)//we want db
          $returnarray[] = $db_outage;

        elseif($db_starttime > $report_starttime && $db_endtime <= $report_endtime)//we want report
          $returnarray[] = $report_outage;

        else
          //what here
        }
      }
   return $returnarray;
  }
```

However I'm not getting what I want. Can someone please point me in the right direction or if someone has some example code that would be fantastic!

Again, for every element I need to check if it is (partially) "between" a start/end i already have and if it is bigger "expand" (or relapse) the original entry. If for example it fits right in it means I already have it so I won't need that entry.

edit:
Added copy/paste if you want to use my data

```
    $outage_array = array();
    $outage_array[] = array(1397635320, 1397635440);
    $outage_array[] = array(1397635740, 1397635920);
    $outage_array[] = array(1397636700, 1397637300);
    $outage_array[] = array(1397641260, 1397641980);
    $outage_array[] = array(1397642640, 1397642760);
    $outage_array[] = array(1397643240, 1397647740);

    $report_array = array();
    $report_array[] = array(1397636580, 1397637300);
    $report_array[] = array(1397641080, 1397641980);
    $report_array[] = array(1397643120, 1397647800);
```

edit: I'll try to describe it better:

Take this image:

[image: http://upload.mattie-systems.nl/uploads/6328-naamloos.png]

I have 2 arrays (the red bars) and I want to merge the results to get the blue bar :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this problem right, you can eliminate the if-else construct and just use min/max functions.

```
public static function mergeOutageArrays($db_outages, $report_outages)
{
    $returnarray = array();

    foreach($db_outages as $db_outage) {
        //now match this with report outages
        foreach ($report_outages as $report_outage) {
            $new_start = min($report_outage['starttime'], $db_outage['starttime']);
            $new_end = max($report_outage['endtime'], $db_outage['endtime']);

            $returnarray[] = array($new_start, $new_end);
         }
    }
    return $returnarray;
}
```

And since you are only referencing each element once, there is no need to copy the values to a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately this is not what i need. I've updated my question with a new image that (hopefully) explains better what I need.

Comment: @Matthijs, because of your middle case (where you take the start from one array and the end of the other), you have to check the beginnings and endings separately and assign from the one that fits. Can you tell me which cases my code doesn't work in? When I work through my code with your red input, I get an array that maps to your blue output.